# What is this perl object and how do I iterate through it?

Tags: perl

I have a perl object that was returned to me whose data I can't seem to extract.  If I run Data::Dumper->Dump on it as:

```
Data::Dumper->Dump($message_body)
```

I get:

```
$VAR1 = 'SBM Message
';
$VAR2 = '--SBD.Boundary.605592468
';
$VAR3 = 'Content-Type: text/plain;charset=US-ASCII
';
$VAR4 = 'Content-Disposition: inline
```

If I execute the line:

```
print $message_body;
```

I get:

```
ARRAY(0x9145668)
```

I would think this is an array.  However, trying to iterate through it there only seems to be a single element.  How do I extract each of the elements from this?  By the way this, is  basically the body of a mail message extracted using the MIME::Parser package.  It was created using the following:

```
my $parser = new MIME::Parser;
my $entity = $parser->parse($in_fh); # Where $in_fh points to a mail message
$message_body = $entity->body;
```

Comment: You're misusing `Data::Dumper->Dump`. It would be more obvious if you used it properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below `foreach` loop.

```
foreach my $item (@{$message_body})
{
   print $item."\n";
}
```

`$message_body` is an ARRAY reference. Hence you need to dereference it and then iterate through each element using the `foreach` loop.

**Read:**

http://perlmeme.org/howtos/using_perl/dereferencing.html and http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/perl-array-reference-examples/

Answer (score -1):

`Data::Dumper` is only a poor man's choice to see the content.
To see all the gory internal details use `Devel::Peek` instead.

```
use Devel::Peek;
Dump $message_body;
```